# Nested PIPELINED function is skipped by Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'll post a trivial example, which actually works, just to get an approximate picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

Here is the 'inner' function which takes the data from some table, called `test_tab`:

```
create or replace function test_inner RETURN num_typ PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR cur in (
    SELECT x FROM test_tab
  )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(cur.x);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Here is the 'outer' function which uses the result of `inner` function and transforms them appropriately:

```
create or replace function test_outer RETURN num_typ PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (
    SELECT * FROM table(test_inner())
  )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(x.column_value * 2);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And here is how I use it:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'insert into test_tab(x) values(1)';
  execute immediate 'insert into test_tab(x) values(2)';
  execute immediate 'insert into test_tab(x) values(3)';

  FOR x IN (
    select * from table(test_outer())
  ) LOOP  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(x.column_value);
  END LOOP;  
end;
/
```

The problem is that `test_inner` function seems to be ignored by Oracle. When it is called separately, it 'sees' the data inserted prior to its execution. But when it's called as a part of `test_outer` it doesn't return any data, or maybe doesn't get called at all.

Like I said, the above example will work. But my case is a little bit more complex, so I can't post it entirely.

Comment: It's a bit hard to diagnose a problem you haven't demonstrated. Unless you can come up with a test case that shows the problem I'm not sure it's possible to explain what you're seeing, since we can't see it. Aside from a bug, and assuming it isn't something as trivial as not having `serveroutput` off, the only things I can even think to ask are whether everything is in onse schema, and whether your `test_outer` is declared as autonomous.

Comment: @AlexPoole Agreed. I tried to come up with a simple reproducible test case, but failed to do so. The function I'm trying to debug is quite huge, so it's difficult to isolate the problem. `SERVEROUTPUT` is on. The weird part is that when I switch `test_inner` to some real table which contains the required data, `test_outer` does return the expected result. And when dumping the contents of this real table and comparing it to the output from `test_inner` function called separately, just after the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements, I could see that they are absolutely identical.

Comment: @AlexPoole One other thing, that I forgot to mention, is that when I put a `COMMIT` after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements, the `test_outer` returns the expected result. But I don't know how to explain this. It's as if Oracle spawns a new session for executing `test_inner`, because it looks like it doesn't see any data until COMMIT is issued.

Comment: Switching to `test_tab`, or a different real table? Is `test_tab` a GTT, or a normal table, or a view? It shouldn't, but does using straight inserts instead of dynamic ones make a difference? Or committing the inserts? Could anything be rolling back the inserts before you call the function (another proc call, or a trigger on a different change deleting them, say)? Just throwing out ideas... probably all things you've checked already.

Comment: Re. the commit - neither of the functions have `pragma autonomous_transaction`?

Comment: @AlexPoole Nope, just plain pipelined functions. But I just recalled that the `test_outer` is actually called in some wrapper function, which controls the test execution, so I will have to double-check that this wrapper doesn't roll anything back. Thanks a ton for your ideas! I'll write more when I find a solution. I hope it's going to be something trivial. I just thought that maybe there is a known issue with nesting pipelined functions.

Comment: @AlexPoole Turned out, the problem wasn't related to PIPELINED functions, but rather to very complex WITH query, with many interrelated and joined subqueries, and for some obscure reason, Oracle hadn't evaluated one of those subqueries correctly. I'll post an update, as soon as I get a reproducible test case.

Answer (score 3):

The test case you have posted does not reproduce the problem you claim to be seeing.  So it is not a test case.

@AlexPoole has provided you with some other ideas.  Basically there is nothing further we can do unless you can post a better test case, given that you cannot post the entire things (and we don't want to go through hundreds of lines of somebody else's shonky code - I for one get enough of that debugging my own stuff).

Producing a poor test case has not been a waste of time.  At least you can rule out certain things: it's nothing to do with one pipelined function calling another.  So it's clearly something in your specific implementation.  Perhaps not in the internal function logic, but how they are called, the data they work with or some other part of the infrastructure.

All you can do is analyse the individual parts.  Start with the core component, and build out, adding other components until you find the bit which breaks.  Yes this is a tedious chore.  But from your comments it sounds like you're quite a way through this process already.

---

I'm marking this CW as it isn't an answer to the question, just an extended comment.

Answer (score -1):

Your both **pipelined** functions in fact are syntactic wrong: you are missing **RETURN**

[See docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS836)

Comment: Although the docs do mandate the `RETURN;` statement for pipelined functions, in fact they will compile *and work* without one.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: The fact it works doesn't mean it correct.what happens is it works because the nature of PIPELINED is async; so as soon as data item available it gets returned to the calling environment; so it seems that it "correct". However, each function must have a return statement due to its "nature"  of being function. you should know that just like in low level language, when a "call" happens ,the caller is "pushed" onto stack, and callee does it work. Pipelined case is **async**; caller doesn't have to wait for full completion of callee! But memory aint released if no return from called function.

Comment: I agree with you that it is best to include the RETURN statement.  I'm merely disputing that its absence is the cause of the OP's problem.  So, this is not really an answer.